# (python): split after each dot into a new line and capitalize each first letter of each line with keeping the dots

Tags: python

(python)
I'm trying to get an input from the user (a sentence that contains many dots), and then split the sentence to a new line after each dot and capitalize every first letter of each line.

```
    s=input("enter a sentence with donts\n")
    csn=s.split(".")
    for i in csn:
        cap=csn.upper()
        print(cap)
```

input:

```
i love.python.it's. great.
```

output
    I love
    Python
    I'ts 
    Great 
how can I keep the dots? like this

```
I love.
Python.
It's.
Great.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `str.capitalize` to make the first chracter of each word a capital letter (if appropriate), and `str.strip` to remove excess spaces:

```
print('\n'.join([i.strip().capitalize() for i in s.split('.')]))
```

prints

```
I love
Python
It's
Great
```